# Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference in perl

Tags: perl, reference

I'm getting an error message `Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference`.

I can't work out what I'm doing wrong based on [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9040302/cant-use-an-undefined-value-as-a-symbol-reference) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387930/cant-use-an-undefined-value-as-a-symbol-reference-on-line-12) to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16391047/cant-use-an-undefined-value-as-a-symbol-perl):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Enter sequences to print (six1 = 0 eya1 = 1 six1-eya1 = 2): ";
chomp($seqs_to_print = <STDIN>);
```

**The line later in the program that throws the error:**

```
print $sequences ">$xlocs $gene $condition \n$eya_seqs{$xlocs}\n" if $seqs_to_print == 1;
```

I'm opening the `$sequences` filehandle as below:

```
unless ($flag1 eq '-s'){
open my $sequences, '>', '/Users/Desktop/sequences.txt' or die $!;
}
```

So scoping can't be an issue.

I also don't get any errors if I use

```
print $sequences ">$xlocs $gene $condition \n$eya_seqs{$xlocs}\n";
```

Note: I can see what might be confusing in my question: The first character for FASTA files is a '>', which I want to prepend my `xlocs` with. It's not a `read in`.

Here is the code surrounding the line that throws the error:

```
unless ($flag1 eq '-s'){

    sub sequence {
        my (%seqs, $xloc);
        my ($xlocs, $c, $e, $ch, $gene, $count, $condition) = @_;
        $gene =~ s/^ //g;
        print $sequences ">$xlocs $gene $condition \n$six_seqs{$xlocs}\n" if $seqs_to_print == 0;
        print $sequences ">$xlocs $gene $condition \n$eya_seqs{$xlocs}\n" if $seqs_to_print == 1;
        print $sequences ">$xlocs $gene $condition \n$sixeya1_seqs{$xlocs}\n" if $seqs_to_print == 2;
    }

}
```

Comment: It looks like `$xlocs` is undefined at that point. What code do you think should be assigning it a value?

Comment: Don't think it's `$xlocs` that's erroring. If you do that, you get: `Use of uninitialized value $xlocs in hash element `

Comment: Was `$sequences` defined in the part of the program not shown?

Comment: I would have to assume so, because if not - `strict` and `warnings` would elicit a different error.

Comment: Are you checking the return code from that `open`? But either way, the open failing _would generate a different error. (`print() on closed filehandle`)

Comment: Could you add `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper $sequences;` just before that subroutine? (And again for the other variables used in there).

Comment: @Sobrique - Dumper doesn't print anything when added immediately before the sub

Comment: OK. Looking at your edit - you've put a `my` inside an `unless` block. That means it goes out of scope as soon as your `unless` block exits. That's what's causing you problems. And by "prints nothing" do you mean literally? Because at the very least you should get: `$VAR1 = undef;` or similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error is generated by `print` when the file handle it's writing to is undefined.

E.g.:

```
my $test = undef;
print $test "some text";
```

Will generate that same error. Without seeing what you're doing to define `$sequences` I can't tell you why - but did you check the return codes from `open`?

Assuming `$sequences` is a filehandle of course. If it isn't, then you might want to just stick a comma in there instead.

```
print $sequences, ">$xlocs $gene $condition \n$eya_seqs{$xlocs}\n" if $seqs_to_print == 1;
```

Are you using the code referenced:

```
sub open_save{
    open(my $fh, '>', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
}
```

Because this will have exactly the same result - you will open `$fh` and it'll instantly go out of scope and become undefined (and close). Which will have this result. But `use strict;` and `use warnings` should tell you if `$sequences` is out of scope.

Edit:

Based on your code update - I'm afraid the *only* way I can elicit the error message you're seeing, is by `$sequence` being undefined.

However, you *are* creating a sub within another code block - that's a bit unusual, and I would imagine not what you actually intended.

The only way I can get something similar - using some dummy data - is:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $sequences;
my %six_seqs;
my %eya_seqs;
my %sixeya1_seqs;
my $flag1 = "-not_s"; 
my $seqs_to_print = 1;

unless ($flag1 eq '-s'){

    sub sequence {
        my (%seqs, $xloc);
        my ($xlocs, $c, $e, $ch, $gene, $count, $condition) = @_;
        $gene =~ s/^ //g;
        print $sequences ">$xlocs $gene $condition \n$six_seqs{$xlocs}\n" if $seqs_to_print == 0;
        print $sequences ">$xlocs $gene $condition \n$eya_seqs{$xlocs}\n" if $seqs_to_print == 1;
        print $sequences ">$xlocs $gene $condition \n$sixeya1_seqs{$xlocs}\n" if $seqs_to_print == 2;
    }

}

sub some_other_code {
    open ( my $sequences, ">", "sequence_file" ) or warn $!;
    sequence ( 1,2,3,4,5,6 );
    close ( $sequences );
}

some_other_code();
```

This gives the same error, and it's because `$sequences` is undefined *during* the sequence `sub`.

Solutions to this problem involve passing the filehandle in through the subroutine - but you can also "see" what's going on by:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper $sequences;
```

Try this just before your error line(s) and see if that gives you anything interesting.

Edit: (Further edit):

```
unless ($flag1 eq '-s'){
    open my $sequences, '>', '/Users/Desktop/sequences.txt' or die $!;
}
```

This is what's causing your problem - that `my` defined `$sequences` as *within that block* - and it goes `undef` as soon as you exit the `unless` block.

Comment: Even a failed `open` call will initialize the lexical filehandle variable. I'm guessing there never was an `open`.

Comment: Possibly. The code referenced does an open in a `sub`, with a lexically scoped filehandle which'll have the same result.

Comment: @Sobrique - This can't be the case. Running the program without the `if $seqs_to_print == 1;` runs without error. The scope of the `$fh` is unchanged

Comment: If `$seqs_to_print` was `undef`, you would get `Use of uninitialized value $test in numeric eq (==)`. Think you need to give us a bit more code here - it might be the error is a 'run over' from a previous line that's missing a semicolon or siimilar.

Comment: If it's a string, you get: `Argument isn't numeric in numeric eq (==)`

Comment: Updated answer - I'm still having problems reproducing your error based on the value (or otherwise) of `$seqs_to_print` - unless of course, the print is simply not happening.